# Android layout are fixed?

Tags: android

I am putting more than 15 buttons in one .xml file. But it seem only to be displaying the top 9 of them ? Why aren't the other buttons showed or can't I scroll down to see them?

I am using a LinearLayout with  tags.

Comment: Please paste your XML so we can provide assistance.

Comment: Im using LinearLayout with <Button> within it

Comment: Kenneth Lhv, you can edit your own question to add your XML (no need to put it in the comments). This way, we will be able to help better and faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you use this?

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

Please post your code,

Comment: <LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="@drawable/bg">
   <Button 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/badrul" 
    android:text="Badrul Songket Batik" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>
Cant list out all the button codes, insufficient space.

Answer (score 3):

Are you using a `LinearLayout` perhaps to contain the buttons? Or any other layout that's not contained in a `ScrollView`? Good chance your buttons are being drawn, they are just outside your screen.

Wrap your layout in a `ScrollView` like so:

```
 <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:scrollbars="none" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <!-- your buttons here -->
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
```

This makes your layout scrollable, so you will be able to just scroll down and see your buttons.

Answer (score 2):

Are you wrapping everything is `ScrollView`?:

```
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
</ScrollView>
```

More info http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html